# NullPointerException while returning a JLabel

Tags: random, nullpointerexception, shuffle

i seem to have a nullPointerException without any reason, could you please review piece of my code and tell me your opinion?
This is the class and the constructor that i am calling on another class in order to get a label randomly (using the shuffle, which is randomizing as well) from a linked list.
here is the

```
public class RandomHeuristic {

    GameInterface game;
    JLabel randomLabel;
    public JLabel RandomHeuristic() {
        randomLabel = (JLabel) game.labels.getFirst();
        int counter = 0;
        do {
            Collections.shuffle(game.labels);
            randomLabel = (JLabel) game.labels.getFirst();
            counter++;
            if (counter == 100) {
                break;
            }
            /*
             * Debugging
             * System.out.println(randomLabel.getText());
             */
        } while (randomLabel != null && game.isLegalMove(randomLabel) == false);
        //Retrieves and removes the head (first element) of this list.
        if(randomLabel == null){
            RandomHeuristic();
        }
        //game.labels.remove(randomLabel);
        return randomLabel;
    }
}
```

And here is where i am calling the constructor, the playHeuristicMove() is expecting a JLabel i checked it on debugging that is working correctly, though i still get a nullPointer Exception when i call it. randomHeuristicOne is created on the same class like this: `RandomHeuristic randomHeuristicOne;`
`playHeuristicMove(randomHeuristicOne.RandomHeuristic());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you want to take a look at your `game` `GameInterface` object it seems it's never been instantiated

Comment: what do you mean it is never initiated? i am creating it and then i am  the label returned is done through that? do you mean something else maybe?

Comment: @SkatZ GameInterface game.. that field seems to be null since you have not created the instance. The new operator will create an instance for you so try: GameInterface game = new GameInterface(); (if it is a Java interface then use the implementer class) before making the game.labels.getFirst() call

Comment: I tried it, it is still not working! any other ideas why that is null?